# Facing this error while classifying Images, containing 10 classes in pytorch, in ResNet50. My code is:

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, resnet

This is the code I am implementing: I am using a subset of the CalTech256 dataset to classify images of 10 different kinds of animals. We will go over the dataset preparation, data augmentation and then steps to build the classifier.

```
def train_and_validate(model, loss_criterion, optimizer, epochs=25):
    '''
    Function to train and validate
    Parameters
        :param model: Model to train and validate
        :param loss_criterion: Loss Criterion to minimize
        :param optimizer: Optimizer for computing gradients
        :param epochs: Number of epochs (default=25)

    Returns
        model: Trained Model with best validation accuracy
        history: (dict object): Having training loss, accuracy and validation loss, accuracy
    '''

    start = time.time()
    history = []
    best_acc = 0.0

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        epoch_start = time.time()
        print("Epoch: {}/{}".format(epoch+1, epochs))

        # Set to training mode
        model.train()

        # Loss and Accuracy within the epoch
        train_loss = 0.0
        train_acc = 0.0

        valid_loss = 0.0
        valid_acc = 0.0

        for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_data_loader):

            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)

            # Clean existing gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # Forward pass - compute outputs on input data using the model
            outputs = model(inputs)

            # Compute loss
            loss = loss_criterion(outputs, labels)

            # Backpropagate the gradients
            loss.backward()

            # Update the parameters
            optimizer.step()

            # Compute the total loss for the batch and add it to train_loss
            train_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)

            # Compute the accuracy
            ret, predictions = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            correct_counts = predictions.eq(labels.data.view_as(predictions))

            # Convert correct_counts to float and then compute the mean
            acc = torch.mean(correct_counts.type(torch.FloatTensor))

            # Compute total accuracy in the whole batch and add to train_acc
            train_acc += acc.item() * inputs.size(0)

            #print("Batch number: {:03d}, Training: Loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {:.4f}".format(i, loss.item(), acc.item()))


        # Validation - No gradient tracking needed
        with torch.no_grad():

            # Set to evaluation mode
            model.eval()

            # Validation loop
            for j, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(valid_data_loader):
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)

                # Forward pass - compute outputs on input data using the model
                outputs = model(inputs)

                # Compute loss
                loss = loss_criterion(outputs, labels)

                # Compute the total loss for the batch and add it to valid_loss
                valid_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)

                # Calculate validation accuracy
                ret, predictions = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                correct_counts = predictions.eq(labels.data.view_as(predictions))

                # Convert correct_counts to float and then compute the mean
                acc = torch.mean(correct_counts.type(torch.FloatTensor))

                # Compute total accuracy in the whole batch and add to valid_acc
                valid_acc += acc.item() * inputs.size(0)

                #print("Validation Batch number: {:03d}, Validation: Loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {:.4f}".format(j, loss.item(), acc.item()))

        # Find average training loss and training accuracy
        avg_train_loss = train_loss/train_data_size 
        avg_train_acc = train_acc/train_data_size

        # Find average training loss and training accuracy
        avg_valid_loss = valid_loss/valid_data_size 
        avg_valid_acc = valid_acc/valid_data_size

        history.append([avg_train_loss, avg_valid_loss, avg_train_acc, avg_valid_acc])

        epoch_end = time.time()

        print("Epoch : {:03d}, Training: Loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {:.4f}%, \n\t\tValidation : Loss : {:.4f}, Accuracy: {:.4f}%, Time: {:.4f}s".format(epoch, avg_train_loss, avg_train_acc*100, avg_valid_loss, avg_valid_acc*100, epoch_end-epoch_start))

        # Save if the model has best accuracy till now
        torch.save(model, dataset+'_model_'+str(epoch)+'.pt')

    return model, history

# Load pretrained ResNet50 Model
resnet50 = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
#resnet50 = resnet50.to('cuda:0')


# Freeze model parameters
for param in resnet50.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
# Change the final layer of ResNet50 Model for Transfer Learning
fc_inputs = resnet50.fc.in_features

resnet50.fc = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(fc_inputs, 256),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Dropout(0.4),
    nn.Linear(256, num_classes), # Since 10 possible outputs
    nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1) # For using NLLLoss()
)

# Convert model to be used on GPU
# resnet50 = resnet50.to('cuda:0')

# Change the final layer of ResNet50 Model for Transfer Learning
fc_inputs = resnet50.fc.in_features

resnet50.fc = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(fc_inputs, 256),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Dropout(0.4),
    nn.Linear(256, num_classes), # Since 10 possible outputs
    nn.LogSoftmax(dienter code herem=1) # For using NLLLoss()
)

# Convert model to be used on GPU
# resnet50 = resnet50.to('cuda:0')`enter code here`
```

Error is this:

> ---
>
> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         6 # Train the model for 25 epochs
>         7 num_epochs = 30
>   ----> 8 trained_model, history = train_and_validate(resnet50, loss_func, optimizer, num_epochs)
>         9 
>        10 torch.save(history, dataset+'_history.pt')
>
> in train_and_validate(model,
>   loss_criterion, optimizer, epochs)
>        43 
>        44             # Compute loss
>   ---> 45             loss = loss_criterion(outputs, labels)
>        46 
>        47             # Backpropagate the gradients
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in
>   **call**(self, *input, **kwargs)
>       539             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
>       540         else:
>   --> 541             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>       542         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
>       543             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py in
>   forward(self, input, target)
>       202 
>       203     def forward(self, input, target):
>   --> 204         return F.nll_loss(input, target, weight=self.weight, ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
>       205 
>       206
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in
>   nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce,
>   reduction)    1836                          .format(input.size(0),
>   target.size(0)))    1837     if dim == 2:
>   -> 1838         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)    1839     elif dim == 4:    1840         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target,
>   weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
>
> RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes'
>   failed.  at
>   C:\Users\builder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-0i480kur\aten\src\THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:97

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when there are either incorrect labels in your dataset, or the labels are 1-indexed (instead of 0-indexed). As from the error message, `cur_target` must be smaller than the total number of classes (10). To verify the issue, check the maximum and minimum label in your dataset. If the data is indeed 1-indexed, just minus one from all annotations and you should be fine.

Note, another possible reason is that there exists some -1 labels in the data. Some (esp older) datasets use -1 as indication of a wrong/dubious label. If you find such labels, just discard them.